# tow message send to telegram bot (Same Time)

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf, node-telegram-bot-api

I am making a contest bot. I have a problem. When the user sends the answer to the question in one breath, it gives a point to both users and repeat next question. I want a point to be calculated for the one with the fastest answer.
Thank you

[click to look at code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMI7D.jpg)

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It clearly says: "DO NOT post images of code".

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that messages will arrive at the same time. Even if they will be sent together because it depends on:

- your hosting network;
- Telegram servers - there are multiple of them and 2 messages can go to different (more busy);
- User network;
- User device and app response time.

Everything together can't give you the same time, but may give almost the same time - few ms difference (50-500).

Comment: Thx for replay, My problem The two messages are dealt at the same time, then the following question is repeated and given two points for each user

Comment: @Coder so what is your problem now?

Comment: @Coder is this question still relevant?